# Normal Subspaces of Tychonoff Cubes

Tags: general-topology, compactification

I know that the completely regular spaces are exactly the subspaces of Tychonoff cubes (possibly uncountable powers of $[0,1]$).  Out of these, the compact Hausdorff spaces are exactly the closed subspaces of Tychonoff cubes.  Is there a way to describe the class of subspaces of Tychonoff cubes that are exactly the class of normal spaces?

Where I've gotten so far:

Sufficient conditions for normality:  Second countability, Closedness, Countability of $\lambda$.

Necessary conditions for normality:  It isn't [this counterexample](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/the-uncountable-product-of-the-countable-discrete-space-is-not-normal/).

Comment: The example only implies that $(0,1)^I \subseteq [0,1]^I$ is not normal.

Answer (score 1):

You're really just asking for conditions for a space $X$ to to be $T_4$ (i.e. normal and $T_1$). Any such space embeds as a (thus normal) subspace of $[0,1]^{w(X)}$. E.g. any $F_\sigma$ subset of $[0,1]^I$ is normal (as it is $\sigma$-compact hence Lindelöf and a Lindelöf and regular space is normal. 
But this is not at all a necessary condition. Even $G_\delta$ subsets need not be normal.

The description is just : the normal subspaces of $[0,1]^I$ are the subspaces that are normal (insert definition here). You cannot expect better. Or you'd just have a characterisation of normality in general.